# ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite' in jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins-pipeline, llvmlite

In my requirement.txt file I've added some packages but below error is thrown in jenkins pipeline output-

```
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I also tried keeping PIP upgrade as true and false for each run but no luck.
Also, tried checking dependent packages for llvmlite and removed from requirement.txt file.

Any other alternative way which I can try?

Responses are highly appreciated.